# Products not getting added to cart, even after Backorder is enabled

Tags: magento2, backorder

I am using magento 2.4.3-p1.

I have enabled backorder, https://prnt.sc/wJYpF1_3dQm0
The product stock status is set as "In stock" for configurable product and its associated simple products too.https://prnt.sc/8Ydrqu_FaFDD https://prnt.sc/pBhG8NMCz_2X

When i try to add the product to cart from frontend, it is showing error as "The requested qty is not available. https://prnt.sc/ObXyOCf4HW-B

Can anyone help me in resolving this?

Comment: you did reindexing?? ``php bin/magento indexer:reindex``

Comment: yes, i did......

Comment: how did you solved this?